# Alternative methods to search, without using FT Search

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino

I am currently using the 'search in view results' option in the view control to provide the data set for my view (the reason for this is that the data set to be displayed is fairly complex depending on the user - and I was not able to accomplish this using vector filtering).

The problem I have with it, is that the search is a FT search, and that it does not let you search where a field is an exact match on a string, but rather it does a search where the field contains your string.

Does anyone know of an method where I can search the view for exact data?

Thanks in advance.

A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your database is not too big you could use a database.search. It uses an @Formula to get the documents. It might be by a magnitude slower than FT Search

Comment: This was the path I wanted to initially go down because the view index is updated quicker than the FT index, and can be small dataset making the search faster. Excuse the question, but how do I do a database.search in xPages? I have made an assumption that I can only do an FT Search in the view as the 'search in view results' option only allows you to do a FT search. I'm not sure where to manipulate the dataset returned in the view.  Have I stepped straight over something really obvious?

Comment: It is a method of the database. You would use it inside a data table or a repeat control, not a view control. And view.ftsearch is by magnitudes slower than db.ftsearch when your resultset is large and you only show a subset first

Comment: Thanks for the pointer @stwissel - had only been thinking of using a view control as I only need to show the data in a fairly standard manner - will look into both the data table and repeat control.  Tks.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this code http://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=build-a-search-query I think it could help you do what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks @rrumaner - my understanding of this is that it is still doing an FT search, and a limitation of the FT Search is that whilst it will search for an exact string, it does not let you search for a match on an exact field - it always does a 'contains' search (shorthand is =, to make it more confusing).

Comment: Take the searchsite template apart. It reveals all the nitty gritty of FTSearch. It is the fastest.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you want to do, a better option is to create a hidden view with the columns you need to match on. Then search on that view rather then an FTI search.